# Get a value of a dataframe based on a string in the previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello  I have a folder with many excel files and I would like to make a datatape with the value of the cell which is next to a specific string ("Value (€)"). Excels are not consistent so I don't know which column contains the value that I want.

This is an example of my data frame. I want to get the '100'.

[image]

This my code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(".....xlsx")
df=df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains("Value",regex=False).any(),axis=1)]
test = (df.values=="Value (€)").any(axis=0)
cols= [df.columns[idx] for idx in np.where(test==True)[0]]
df=df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_indexer(cols)+1]
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a Boolean array indicating which cells contain the string of interest. Then you can shift this array one column to the right by adding a column of all `False` to the left and slicing off the last column. This new array you can use as a mask to filter out the values you want:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['asd', 'asd', 'asd'], 
                   'col2': ['asd', 'asd', 'asd'], 
                   'col15': ['Value (€)', 'asd', 'asd'], 
                   'col16': [100, 'asd', 'asd'], })

mask = np.hstack([np.repeat(False, len(df)).reshape(-1, 1), 
                  (df.values == 'Value (€)')[:, :-1]])

print(df.values[mask])
```

```
[100]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Hello @Arne , some of my excel files include horizontally merged cells so there are NaN outputs. Is there any way to make your code work and ignore NaN values?

Comment: Hello @Tsorts - The code should work with `df` containing NaN values too. Just make sure the missing values are all `np.nan`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.nan

Comment: With your code I get the value next to the cell that has text "Value (€)". However, there are cases where the cell with the text "Value (€)" is merged with the cell to the right. so I get Nan value.